# Deleting a record from the list in angularjs

Tags: jquery, mysql, angularjs

Hi iam trying to delete a record from the list when i click on delete button it is showing as successfully deleted and the record is not dispalying which i deleted once i refresh the page it is displaying the record.Here i need to delete the record by comparing both email and id.Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<thead>           
        <th style="padding:15px;">Name</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="salary in salaryInfo">            
    <td>{{salary.name}}</td>
    <td>{{salary.income}}</td>        
    <td>
    <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="removeRow(salary.companyname)"/>
    </td>
      </tr>
```

Javascript

```
$scope.removeRow = function(){              
    $scope.salaryInfo = [];

        $http({
              method    : 'POST',
              url       : '../model/deleteincomesources.php',             
              headers   : {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            },
              data      : {"action": "DeleteIncomeSources"}

            })
            .success(function(data, status, headers) {
            console.log("Response data:"+ JSON.stringify(data));
            if (data.success != undefined && data.success != '')
              {

                $scope.salaryInfo.push(data);                       
              }

            }).error(function(data, status, headers) {
                alert("Error occured while Deleting Data:"+status);
                console.log("Error data::::"+ data);
                console.log("status::::"+ status);
                        });             
};
```

SQL:

```
$res = "DELETE  FROM user_salary_details  WHERE email=$userEmailid";
$result=mysql_query($res);
```

Comment: Perhaps `WHERE email='$userEmailid'`

Comment: I need to compare id as well but how to get that id

Answer (score 0):

you are passing salary.companyname as the parameter while on your delete query there is check on email on delete query check must be on companyname not on emailID